# How do i fix this fatal:bad boolean config value

Tags: git, github, fatal-error, git-push, git-add

$ git push
fatal: bad boolean config value 'origin' for 'push.autosetupremote'

I want to push in git but an error appears as above
im using new version git

I hope to be able to git push some of my projects to the github repository

Answer (score 1):

The value of `push.autosetupremote` should be boolean like `true`, `false`, `1` or `0`.

First find out where the value is set. Run `git config --show-origin push.autosetupremote`. It prints the config path and the value.

Then edit the config file. You can remove `autosetupremote = origin` or modify the value.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to check your Git configurations related to push.autosetupremote:

```
git config --get-regexp push.autosetupremote
```

If you see a wrong value set for push.autosetupremote, you can reset it by using the command:

```
git config --unset push.autosetupremote
```

You might want to set it up again if needed. For example:

```
git config --global push.autosetupremote tracking
```

This will configure Git to set up the remote tracking branch when you create a new local branch.

After making these changes, try pushing your changes again:

```
git push
```

This should resolve the issue related to the push.autosetupremote configuration. If the problem persists or if you encounter any other errors, feel free to provide more details about the error message for further assistance!